# How I can set two elements in children method?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to set - `cy.get('').children('div').children('div').click()`.
Can I change `.children('div').children('div')` to one children function instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
cy.get('some selector').children('div1').find('div2').click()
```

OR, you can directly use `find()` as well if that works for your case:

```
cy.get('some selector').find('div2').click()
```